# Fatal signal without exception

Tags: android

Sometimes, in my Android App, I get this kind of error :

```
05-15 15:37:26.269: A/libc(21860): heap corruption detected by dlmalloc
05-15 15:37:26.269: A/libc(21860): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00005564 (code=-6), thread 21860 (rot.appname)
```

I can't understand why it append and there are no error traces in the logcat, so I'm not able to debug it.

Is someone know a way to debug it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I'm working with ndk.

Comment: Something with pointers. I had the same error when tried to use pointer from another thread.

Comment: Ok thanks. I've got a looooot of pointers. Who can I know which pointer is wrong ?

Comment: Oh, its the problem. Try to write to log something to detect where is the problem. Especially where you use malloc.

Comment: Now, posting some code could be useful :)

Comment: There are a lot of files, so I can't post it here...